# Django admin inline for deep relation

Tags: django, django-admin

It's quite easy to have inline for direct relation, but how can I create inline for deeper relations?

Let's say situation is like

```
class A(models.Model):
     ...

class B(models.Model):
     a = models.ForeignKey(A)

class C(models.Model):
     b = models.ForeignKey(B)
```

Now what I'd like to have is inline in admin for `A` which will show all of it's `C`s with corresponding `B` name. How do I do that?

Comment: You could patch some admin and form methods, but that will tend to get messy. I'd recommend creating your own custom formset and [prepend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls) the admin views accordingly.

Comment: Or use a package dependency as stalk's answer suggests

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [django-nested-inlines](https://github.com/n3ls0n/django-nested-inlines). From example:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from nested_inlines.admin import NestedModelAdmin, NestedStackedInline, NestedTabularInline
from models import A, B, C

class MyNestedInline(NestedTabularInline):
    model = C

class MyInline(NestedStackedInline):
    model = B
    inlines = [MyNestedInline,]

class MyAdmin(NestedModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(A, MyAdmin)
```

Comment: +1 for the effort. However, that would be good solution if nested inlines were officially supported. Unfortunately they are not.