# Django admin TabularLine with custom intermediate fornkey

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have 3 model like this example:

```
class A(models.Model):
      ....

class B(models.Model):
     a = models.ForeignKey(A, ...)
     ....

class C(models.Model):
     b = models.ForeignKey(B, ...)
     ....
```

with this configuration, I would to have in my admin page for model A, a  TabularLine related to the list of model C objects.

Is possible this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django admin inline for deep relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522575/django-admin-inline-for-deep-relation)

Comment: TL;DR it is not possible in a built-in way in Django. Take a look at librairies out there (like [django-nested-inline](https://github.com/s-block/django-nested-inline))